# Cannot convert 'double (*)[5]' to 'double' in return

Tags: c++

I was wondering why do I keep getting an error and unable to return an array;

also, once the sell_item function actually work and return an array..how do I echo that array from the main function.

thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;

int itemnum = 3333;
string itemName="Cooking Range";
int Qauntity=1;

int NumberOfItems=2;
int NumberOfFields=5;

double function_Sell_Item(int   itemnum,string itemName, int Qauntity);

int main () {
    function_Sell_Item(itemnum, itemName, Qauntity);
}

double function_Sell_Item(int   itemnum,string itemName, int Qauntity) {
    double arraylist[2][5];

    for (int index =0; index < NumberOfItems; index++) {
        for (int i=0; i < NumberOfFields; i++) {
            arraylist[index][i]=0;
        }
    }

    return arraylist;
}
//// functions ends
```

:
;

Comment: Qauntity is consistently misspelled in your code.  Also, I suggest learning about pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to return an array, which you cannot do in C++.

You should consider something like `std::vector<double>`, because you can return that.

```
typedef std::vector<double> MyVec;

MyVec foo() {
    MyVec v;
    v.push_back(3.142);
    v.push_back(2.718);
    return v;
}

int main() {
    MyVec z = foo();
    for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << z[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ does allow returning a pointer to an array. Perhaps that's what OP is trying to do. The array would have to be allocated from the heap, of course.

Comment: @TedHopp: Indeed.  So it's best not to go there!

Answer (score 1):

Your code wont work at all as you return a local array, whose memory is not valid anymore after function return. You have to allocate the memory for the array dynamically on the heap.

Furthermore you have to change the return type of your function to `double **`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a double array (two-dimensional) which you can't in C++. 
Use [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead!